# Delphi7 Export B-TreeFiler Database Values

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to export some values out of a btreefiler database. Unfortunately those values has some strange characters inside. I'm using Delphi 7 and the latest library.

Here's an example of the value:

```
#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0##0#0#0#0##0#0#0#0'14-19/32mm'#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0$1A'2'#3#0#0#0#0#0
```

Does anyone know what causes this problem or how to get rid of it?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: what problem? to get rid of what?

Comment: When I try to put those values into (for example) a memo box then the value's are cut after the first null termination. I'm seeking for a solution to convert those characters to real characters if possible to display the values in full length. Unfortunately I'm not very good with Delphi.

Comment: IMHO the null character is a real one, anyway, you just want to get rid of the null characters, or you want to change that characters to other representation. I recommend you to re-think and update your question, as it doesn't state what you want to achieve.

Take a moment to read [how to write the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: What do you mean by "the null character is a real one"? What I want to achieve is to display the value in a memo field without losing any character. This is impossible because the string is null terminated on several positions. I'm not sure what that means. Does this mean the database field includes sub fields? For example field1 -> field1.1, field1.2

Comment: Guys, I think I have just fixed it. I initially misunderstood the structure of the db. It works now. Thanks for your assistance. Do I have to mark this topic as solved somehow?